# How to inspect JQuery UI tooltip?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a default JQuery UI tooltip function call on my page. Is there a way to style the tooltip div interactively using the Inspector? If I had two mouse pointers, one would be hovering over an element to keep the tooltip displayed and second would be using the Inspector and build the style. But I only have one mouse and as soon as it moves off the element, the tooltip disappears. Checking the ":hover" state in Inspector doesn't help. the tooltip disappears on mouse out.

I am using Chrome, but any trick in any browser would do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:hover state in Chrome Developer Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: none, not one in all the given answers work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My working solution in Firefox:
 1. hover over tooltip (tooltip is shown)
 2. hit `CMD-Option-K` (OSX) or `CTRL-Shift-K` (Windows), to open "Web Console"
 3. type "debugger" (this will stop JS execution, so tooltip won't disappear)
 4. open "Inspector" Tab, search for `.ui-tooltip`
 5. edit as necessary. note: changes to CSS will work immediately, even if execution of JavaScript is stopped

Comment: This worked for me like a month ago but doesn't now :( Once I hit the hot key the tooltip disappears. My solution was to run `setTimeout(function(){debugger}, 1000)` in the console, switch back quickly and get the tooltip up.

Comment: This was really useful

Answer (score 12):

In Chrome follow the following steps:
1- Open Developers Tools ( Ctrl + Shift + I ) or (right click on screen and select inspect).

2- Choose Sources:
[image: Choose Sources]

3- On the right side, you found accordion, Open "Event Listener Breakpoints" 
[image: Open "Event Listener Breakpoints"]

4- You will found all events, Open "Mouse", then Select "mouseout" event, this will stop execution of code and stop before "mouseout action".
[image: Open "Mouse", then Select "mouseout"]

5- Go to App screen, and Try to hover only the item which has the tooltip, then screen will freeze, and you will found the tooltip stand as you want.
[image: tooltip stand as you want]

Note: If you hovered other item by wrong, you can resume the execution of code by clicking resume (blue button), and then try hover again.
If you want to return to the normal  execution of code, Deselect the "mouseout" event, and click resume (blue button).
[image: selecting the blue button to resume the execution of code]

In Firefox the same, the difference in "Sources" tab is named "Debugger".

Comment: Thanks, this is a great way to do it

Comment: Best way to do it!

Comment: I'm using Angular tooltip, and for the event to be trapped turned out to be 'mouseleave'.

Answer (score 10):

I found a workaround how to temporary inspect it :

just implement hide settings where you hookup the tooltip logic:

```
hide: {
          effect: "slideDown",
          delay: 20000
      }
```

This gives you 20 sec time to inspect it. If you need more time then increase the "delay" attribute.
Here is my working code for page jquery tooltips:

```
    $(function() {
    $(document).tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "jqueryTooltip",
            content: function() {
                return $(this).attr('title');
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "slideDown",
                delay: 20000
            }
        });
    });
```

After you are done with the inspection just remove the delay and you are done.

Note: I am using custom class "jqueryTooltip" to style the tooltip after inspection.

Answer (score 7):

I'm late to the party, but there is actually a simple way to accomplish this.

In your browser's dev console, use jQuery to target the tooltip as follows:

`$('.selector').tooltip('open');`

In my case, for instance, I have a class `.grey-tooltip` on my tooltip, so I call `$('.grey-tooltip').tooltip('open');`. This should open the tooltips and you can then inspect them as you would any other visible element.

Different methods you can use one tooltips are described in their docs here: https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/.

Comment: `$('.selector').tooltip('show')` for Bootstrap tooltips

Comment: Good suggestion.  In chrome, you can also right-click on the element markup in "Elements" and add an attribute such as an ID in real time if there isn't a good selector to use...

Answer (score 3):

the easy way is to pause js with F8 when tooltip is shown

Comment: In my chrome pressing F8 has no effect

Comment: @Ya. devtools should be opened in Sources tab then F8 will work

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to modify the CSS such that the tool tip is always visible as opposed to  on hover only, at which point you could tweak the div's styling via the inspector and see how it's affected real-time.

Comment: Yes, but which CSS to modify? For example, on this page: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ - if I want to interactively style the tooltip that appears when hovering over the input box ("Your age"), what to do? As far as I noticed, moving the mouse out does not just hide the tooltip, but deletes it from the DOM.

Comment: So it seems, my solution won't work here then. You could look into using a custom div for the tooltip instead of the default title attr. However, I don't see an option for that in the small amount of googling I just did.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the developer tools in the newest Google Chrome you should see the elements tab is selected. On the element you have to hover on you just right click on it and open the 'Force element state' menu to select the :hover option.

Comment: This was the first thing that I tried. But as I wrote in my question, checking the ":hover" state in Inspector doesn't make the tooltip appear, it seems to have no effect on javascript events.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a jQuery tooltip's styling in a browser's inspector, because as you are saying it is removed from the DOM on mouseout.


However, with the following code this is what I did to change to change the styling:

```
$("#myElement").attr({
    title: "my tooltip text"
}).tooltip();

$("#myElement").tooltip({
    // the .tooltip class is applied by default anyway
    tooltipClass: "tooltip"
});
```

1. Type `debugger;` in the JavaScript, before the previous code
2. In Firefox, hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to open [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads) (download it if you don't have it)
3. Select the **Script** tab and click **Reload**
4. Now that the debugger is activated, highlight
   `$("#myElement").tooltip` from the 2nd code block (*without* the parentheses), right-click the highlighted text, and
   select `Add Watch`
5. Under the **Watch** tab in the right window, click on <kbd>+</kbd>
   next to `$("#myElement").tooltip` to expand all the properties
6. Under that expand **Constructor**, then **DEFAULTS**, and then
   **template** to see the HTML that the tooltip is made of

This is then the exposed HTML structure of a jQuery tooltip:

```
<div class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"> ... </div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner"> ... </div>
</div>
```

...and now you can apply CSS, something like this:

```
.tooltip {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.tooltip-arrow {
    /* hackery, placing the arrow where it should be: */
    margin-bottom: -7px;
}
.tooltip-inner {
    /* hackery, making all browsers render the width correctly: */
    width: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;

    /* hackery, removing some unknown applied background: */
    background: none;
    background-color: none;

    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

All the "*hackery*" mentioned in the CSS above is what I had to do to get Bootstrap to play nicely with jQuery (*they both have a `tooltip`, which can conflict with each other -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19247955 for more info*).

Comment: I found some [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HjPtJ/55/), added the debugger command and added the Watch manually (right click didn't work). However, I can't find find the Constructor->DEFAULTS->template, here is the structure that I see: http://s25.postimg.org/7enmrwe9r/img11.jpg

Comment: @camcam -- Wow weird, it appears that jsFiddle augments any JavaScript objects created, so it's probably not possible to see this way. To reproduce what I did, you will need to have this code running in your own HTML.

Comment: I checked this on my real site but the DEFAULTS->template wasn't there anywhere. Also, the tooltip html structure you found is different than what I found (in my answer). Maybe the jQuery ui version was different (I use 1.10).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
jQuery(".myDiv").attr("title", 'Hello');
jQuery(".myDiv").tooltip({close: function( event, ui ) {
  console.log(jQuery(ui.tooltip[0]).html());
}});
```

And the console content was:

```
<div class="ui-tooltip-content">Hello</div>
```

Also, I placed a breakpoint on the `console.log` function and then examined the page structure before the `</body>` end tag, and there was something more:

```
<div id="ui-tooltip-0" role="tooltip" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" style="position: relative; top: -463.60003662109375px; left: 1px; display: block; opacity: 1;"><div class="ui-tooltip-content">Hello</div></div>
```

It was possible to change the tooltip styling on the fly using Inspector (tested in Chrome).