# Mattooltip: How can I make the box fit the text?

Tags: css, angular, tooltip

I have this text that I want to display as tooltip. Without styling (just font-size defined as 16px) it looks like this:

[image]

What I actually want is to have the text displayed in one line - so I set the white-space to pre in the css:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

But now the text goes outside the box of the tooltip:

[image]

I tried setting the width to a higher px value but that did nothing.

Is there a way to make the box fit the text?

**[EDIT - Added missing example as was pointed out in the comments]**: [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tooltip-yyziyd) 
The text in the example does not leave the box but is abbreviated instead of the box fitting around the whole text altough I set the width to 400px.

Comment: And for what it is worth, I would be careful with using `::ng-deep` as it is deprecated in Angular 7

Comment: @Rinktacular Thanks for pointing that out - will fix that too, but that's for another day.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just set the max-width to `unset`. To do so, define a global CSS class as follows:

```css
.my-custom-tooltip {
  max-width: unset !important;
}
```

Then pass the class name to the tooltip:

```html
<button mat-raised-button
        matTooltip="This Infotext is displayed one line if possible. Just a little more text for demo!"
        matTooltipClass="my-custom-tooltip">
  Action
</button>
```

Also as [@rinktacular](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4925564/rinktacular) mentioned, try not to use `ng::deep`.

Working Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkh4cl

**Update (2023-07-23): Workaround for Angular 15+**

The old answer no longer works because Angular Material has migrated to MDC-based components since Angular 15. To solve the problem, you should override the `max-width` rule for the internal MDC CSS class: `mdc-tooltip__surface`. In order to achieve this, define the global CSS class as follows instead:

```css
.my-custom-tooltip .mdc-tooltip__surface {
  max-width: unset !important;
}
```

Working *Stackblitz* example with Angular 16: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ncaweg

Comment: Thx "max-width: unset !important;" does the trick. There is one thing I still don't understand - to what element is it applying the style? If I observe the element in my browser I cannot find the max-width styling on the button or elsewhere ... ?

Comment: Components such as Tooltip, Dialog, etc will be inserted in `cdk-overlay-container`. It's outside of your components hierarchy. You can find the actual tooltip DOM element by inspecting the html. You can see this and the `my-custom-tooltip` CSS rule in the following image: https://i.imgur.com/GTttzJx.png
Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Ah ok - the hover closed on me when I was trying to inspect it, that's why I couldn't see it - thx! If anyone else struggles to inspect the hover check out the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370838/inspect-hovered-element-in-chrome

Comment: If you want to see the actual element in DOM, you can set `matTooltipHideDelay` to a big number, e.g. `matTooltipHideDelay="60000"`

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore for v16+. I tried many different ways but could not get it working...

Comment: Updated answer with the workaround for Angular 16+

Comment: For Angular 17 it's works and I didn't need !important

.custom-tooltip {
    .mdc-tooltip__surface {
        max-width: unset;
    }   
}